# How do I resolve an "expected expression before 'unsigned'" error?

Tags: c

My code is:

```
#include <unistd.h>  

(void)alarm(unsigned int 0);

error: expected expression before 'unsigned'
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Error: expected expression before 'unsigned', due to: (void)alarm(unsigned int 0);

I'm not sure if it is my syntax or use of (void) or something else. What's going on?

I'm using [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) under Windows.

Comment: Try not surrounding the `void` with brackets.

Comment: What is `alarm` supposed to be?  However, I'm not thinking of any place in C where `unsigned int 0` is legal.  You probably want to lose the `0` or put `unsigned int` in parentheses to make it a cast (although `0U` will do nicely instead).

Comment: You need to show us more code. You only showed us two lines in your question. Do you have a two-line source file? I think not.

Comment: I think the questioner has merely copied the two lines from the [man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/alarm.html) into a C file and tried to edit it. i.e. I don't think the questioner even has  `main` function!

Comment: The questioner is using Code::Blocks under Windows, but didn't initially mention that.

Answer (score 4):

Uh, is this meant to be a function call, or is it meant to be a declaration?

If you meant it to be a declaration, then it should be:

```
void alarm( unsigned int i );
```

If you meant it to be a function call, then it should be:

```
(void) alarm( 0 );
```

(Back in my C++ days I used to cast function results to void when I wanted to document the fact that I do not care what the function returned.)

**EDIT:** Then again, if what you are trying to do is to just declare a variable, then try this:

```
unsigned int alarm = 0;
```

Or if you are just trying to set a variable to zero, then things are even more simple:

```
alarm = 0;
```

8-)

Comment: Hello, I started with that, but got this error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant

Comment: @user1088793:  Please show the code you used to get that error.  Either it isn't what MikeNakis supplied, or you've got a strange compiler.

Comment: I dont want to make a variable, I want to set it to 0.

Comment: I think that you must be very fresh with C, so my recommendation at this time would be to start with a book (or some online resource explaining the basics of C) instead of trying to understand it bit by bit by asking a question for each bit.

Comment: @user1088793 in light of your previous comment I edited my answer.

Comment: I am fresh with C, but this is not a complex function I don't think.  I need to learn how to interpret errors some time.

Comment: Because of the complexity of the grammar of the language, compilers quite often give very cryptic or even misleading syntax errors. Even seasoned programmers are sometimes fooled by these syntax errors and resort to considering them as indications of the general location of the error, rather than as descriptions of the actual error. (Of course, do not take me wrong, this does not happen often, and there is always merit in first trying to comprehend the error.)

Comment: Hi mike, I am not trying to declare a variable but schedule an alarm schedule so to avoid some known problems in linux.  Here is notes from an online publication: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/alarm.html   And the exact use of it is that if you set seconds to 0, a pending alarm request, if any are scheduled, is cancelled.

Comment: Okay, so it should be just `(void)alarm( 0 );` or, if your compiler does not like `(void)`, then try just `alarm( 0 );` Which is also what @Charles Bailey answered.

Comment: Ok, but this results in "undefined reference to 'alarm' error again.  I have just downloaded codeblocks gcc and the same error appears. Hmm

Comment: @user1088793, See my answer. Are you trying to write a short C program which calls the `alarm` function?

Comment: MikeNakis' code on ideone is correct. But, @user1088793, that program will not do anything. For example, it will not cancel any other alarms that are in place on your system. I think you need to forget about C programming and explain why you are interested in alarms.  What did you mean what you said you want to "schedule an alarm schedule so to avoid some known problems in linux"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to call the POSIX `alarm` function which takes an `unsigned int` and returns and `unsigned int`.

A correct form of the call would be:

```
alarm(0);
```

There is not normally a need to cast the return value to `void` although it can silence a warning on some compilers.

There is normally no need to explicitly cast `0` to `unsigned int`. The correct form would be `(unsigned int)0`. It is usually simpler to use a suffix where necessary, e.g. `0U` has type `unsigned int` but in this instance plain `0` will work fine.

Additionally, as a function call is not a declaration it must appear inside a function body.

E.g.

```
void foo()
{
    alarm(0);
}
```

Comment: Hi Charles can you tell me what header I need to include please? I just did a test with:  #include <unistd.h> int main() { alarm(0); } as a test and comes up with same undefined reference to 'alarm' error

Comment: `#include <unistd.h>` for `alarm`, but you already had that in your question.

Comment: @user1088793: If you are getting "undefined reference" error, then you have a link error and not a compile error. There is nothing wrong with your `#include`, you just need to link with the appropriate library, in this case try `-lc` as a linker option, although I'm a bit surprised that you don't have that automatically.

Comment: @user1088793: On windows, AFAIK, you'll have to do something else. Windows doesn't support `alarm`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving us enough context to figure out just what you're trying to do.

I'm going to assume that you want to call the `alarm` function with an argument of 0.  According to the man page (type `man alarm` or `man 2 alarm`, or follow [this link](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/alarm.2.html)), `alarm(0)` will cancel any existing alarm without setting a new one.

On my system (Ubuntu, a Linux. i.e., Unix-like system), the following compiles, links, and executes without error:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void) {
    alarm(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I saved the program in a file called `c.c`, and I compiled and linked it with the following command:

```
gcc c.c -o c
```

and executed it with:

```
./c
```

The implementation of the `alarm` function happens to be in the standard C library, which is linked by default.  That might or might not be the case on your system, but if it's Linux or some other Unix-like system, it probably is.

(This isn't a particularly useful program, but it could be a starting point for something useful.

**EDIT :**

I see now that you're using Windows.  The `alarm()` function is defined by the POSIX standard, and is (mostly) specific to Unix-like systems.  Windows probably doesn't provide it by default.  There are Unix-like emulation layers that run under Windows, such as [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com).

But if you want to develop code under Windows, you might consider avoiding non-portable constructs that Windows doesn't (directly) support.

*Why* do you want to call `alarm()`?  Do you have a requirement to do what that particular function does, or are you just trying to learn the basics?

Comment: Hi Keith, I am writing this from windows codeblocks, but compiling from the codeblocks IDE which uses the gcc compiler.

Comment: @user1088793: `alarm()` is part of the runtime library, not part of the compiler.  It's defined by POSIX, which is basically a standard that describes Unix-like operating systems.  The `alarm()` function probably isn't going to be available by default on Windows.  There are Unix/POSIX emulation layers that run under Windows, such as [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com).  (We could have saved some time if you'd mentioned in the first place that you're using Windows; I've just edited your question to add that information.)

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Chiron that this belongs to StackOverflow.

1. You don't need to cast return to `void` just simply ignore it if you choose but better yet don't
2. Why are you declaring variable 0 inside the function call?  Call should be:

   `(void)alarm(0);`

Comment: @user1088793 That means it's a linker error - you are not including the right library, or the signature you are trying to call does not correspond to the method signature of the intended method.

Comment: Sigh :L but I am using the only library that references alarm in this method which is: <unistd.h>

Comment: @user108879: `<unistd.h>` is a header, not a library.  `#include <unistd.h>` lets the compiler see the declaration of the `alarm()`, but it doesn't tell the linker where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    alarm(0);
}
```

I think the question is to write a simple program which calls the [alarm](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/alarm.html) standard function. (See the comment on @MikeNakis's question).

You can't just copy the code from the man page into a program and compile it. You must make a complete program, like the one I have given here.

Comment: Hi I have this and it returns the "undefined reference to 'alarm' error.  I use gcc via codeblocks for c project.

Comment: On the command line, you can do `gcc yourprog.c -o yourprog` and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've included `unistd.h`, I'm assuming you're trying to call the `alarm()` function declared in that header:

```
unsigned int alarm(unsigned int seconds);
```

If you want to call `alarm` with an argument of 0 seconds, simply do `alarm(0)`. You don't need to cast `0` to an `unsigned int`, but if you really wanted to you would just have `alarm( (unsigned)0 );`.

If you don't care about the return type, then just don't assign it to a variable. You don't need to add `(void)` to the start of the function call to ignore the return value. `(void)alarm(0);` is perfectly legal, but also pointless.

And I'm not sure if your snippet is a chopped up example or your actual code, but you can't just call `alarm` from outside of a function like that.

Also, from the man pages:

> If seconds is zero, no new **`alarm()`** is scheduled.

But perhaps you may be wanting to cancel previous alarms:

> In any event any previously set **`alarm()`** is canceled.

**EDIT:** Didn't realise until Keith pointed it out a few minutes ago that you're using Windows. `alarm()` is a *nix function, if you wanted to call it from Windows you could use tools such as *Cygwin* (which is commonly used) to emulate a *nix environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems that all of the answers including alarm() which I think it the simplest form of what I am trying to do but still results in undefined reference to 'alarm' and I have no idea why.

Comment: @user1088793: Can you post the actual code you're compiling that's causing the error? And are you using cygwin?

Comment: sure
    #include <unistd.h>
    int main(void) {
    alarm(0);
    return 0;
    }

Comment: @user1088793: That looks fine, but I just saw you're using Windows to call a \*nix function. You should try *cygwin*.